# Amazon S3, getting "Duplicate headers received" when trying to download file

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, amazon-s3

This only happens in Chrome, works great in Safari. Chrome is complaining that duplicate content-disposition headers are being received. When I upload a file to S3 I set the content disposition so that I can name the file upon download and also ensure it gets downloaded as an attachment (not inline).

Here's what I'm getting specifically:

[image]

Comment: Does the filename include semi-colon's (;) ? I found Chrome choking on it for example at http://www.openbeelden.nl/media/104976#download

Comment: This is happening at Apple's developer center as well. For example (requires logging in with an Apple developer account)

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

When I experienced this error it was because I had something like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file,withcomma.pdf")
```

Chrome is interpreting this as two Content-Disposition headers: "attachment:filename=file" and ",withcomma.pdf".

Wrapping the filename in quotes resolved the issue for me:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"file,withcomma.pdf\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your question and I've just solved mine, though my code is asp.net. I started getting this error today, Chrome must have added some stricter handling of headers. Anyway, my bug turned out to be the part where I set the content-disposition header.

Instead of

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,filename=abcdxyz.pdf")

I changed it to

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=abcdxyz.pdf")

The comma seemed to cause some kind of problem, switching to a semi-colon seems to fix it. It's now working fine for me, but I should mention that I am not familiar with Amazon S3 (at all) so maybe I'm waaaay off, but since it has just worked for me, maybe it'll work for you.

Comment: Another note, while fixing this I noticed that Firefox has a problem with file names if they have spaces. (Chrome and IE are ok with it), the fix for chrome was to wrap the filename value in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated header error on Chrome is a bug with the HTML header: "Content-disposition: attachment" when the filename comes with comma(s).

The solution here, we just add double quotes (") between filename as example:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"file,withcomma.pdf\"")
```

And this solution works for all browsers (as I tested on IE11, Chrome, Firefox)

Answer (score -1):

Original code:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$displayname");
```

changed:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$displayname.'"');
```